Can someone explain the MDN example of using microtasks to ensure consistent ordering of operations?
This example provided to explain tasks vs microtasks doesn’t make sense to me. Shouldn’t the event listener be executed after the current task has finished, so “Data fetched” should get logged before “Loaded data” in the case of it being cached? And in the case of not being cached it’ll be the same because the microtask gets run after the initial task. What am I missing?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide#

One situation in which microtasks can be used to ensure that the
ordering of execution is always consistent is when promises are used
in one clause of an if...else statement (or other conditional
statement), but not in the other clause. Consider code such as this:
customElement.prototype.getData = (url) => {
  if (this.cache[url]) {
    this.data = this.cache[url];
    this.dispatchEvent(new Event("load"));
  } else {
    fetch(url)
      .then((result) => result.arrayBuffer())
      .then((data) => {
        this.cache[url] = data;
        this.data = data;
        this.dispatchEvent(new Event("load"));
      });
  }
};

The problem introduced here is that by using a task in one branch of
the if...else statement (in the case in which the image is available
in the cache) but having promises involved in the else clause, we have
a situation in which the order of operations can vary; for example, as
seen below.
element.addEventListener("load", () => console.log("Loaded data"));
console.log("Fetching data…");
element.getData();
console.log("Data fetched");

Executing this code twice in a row gives the following results.
When the data is not cached:
Fetching data
Data fetched
Loaded data

When the data is cached:
Fetching data
Loaded data
Data fetched



The point of the example is that it doesn't matter, because the real work is being done in the "load" handler. Both paths will make it to that event handler with the data waiting to be used. It doesn't matter how many other tasks happen before that point.

Also your second example is critically different from the first block of code.

"Also your second example is critically different from the first block of code." AFAICT the OP copied everything after the link straight from MDN, so if it's a bad example it isn't really their fault and might be the point of the question...

Yes @JaredSmith I copied it completely. I’m basically asking whether the log order they claim for the cached version is correct

@JaredSmith yea you're right, well I still think it's a weird example, because the claim that it's a problem that after the .getData() function is finished the "data" property might not be set is kind-of spurious, because it's asynchronous and code after the function call shouldn't expect that anyway.

@MattStyles first, apologies for not realizing that. I personally think that example is contrived and not really in touch with how code like that would be written. A transparent cache is supposed to be unnoticeable, so after a .getData() call it would still be bad practice to assume something was fetched immediately from cache, because real caches get flushed, have max-age rules, etc etc. The .getData() here in 2024 really should be an async function.

@Pointy FWIW I totally agree, the article should probably call out how...contrived the example is.

To get at the main point of your confusion: "Shouldn’t the event listener be executed after the current task has finished?" - no, because dispatchEvent is synchronous. This example (apart from generally being a horrible example, as discussed around) is not about tasks vs microtasks. It's about using a microtask vs not using a microtask, with the goal being to avoid releasing zalgo (just like properly using promise would achieve). The use of the event handler is a red hering.

Thanks @Bergi. This is what threw me off “A task is any JavaScript code which is scheduled to be run by the standard mechanisms such as initially starting to run a program, an event callback being run, or an interval or timeout being fired. These all get scheduled on the task queue.” https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide
I believe what’s described in the quote will only happen when it’s a user-triggered event, like an event handler for a button being clicked? If it uses dispatchEvent the handler gets invoked immediately?

@MattStyles Yes, user-triggered events, but also most events from the environment like domready or xhr success events. Basically, any event that gets fired externally, not from within user code, must be put in a task queue and processed asynchronously.

Posting this because it's easier than commenting: now that we have async functions, I think that first example function would me made much clearer by being written that way:
customElement.prototype.getData = async function(url) {
  if (this.cache[url]) {
    this.data = this.cache[url];
    this.dispatchEvent(new Event("load"));
  }
  else {
    const result = await fetch(url);
    const data = await result.arrayBuffer();
    this.cache[url] = data;
    this.data = data;
    this.dispatchEvent(new Event("load"));
  }
  return "getData finished";
};

(Note that another issue with that example was that the function should not be an => function, because this won't work.)
Now in the if there's (effectively) one Promise resolution and in the else there are two, but the problem mentioned in that article is basically "solved". Calling .getData() now (with await):
await element.getData();
// .data will always have been updated here

Kind of skirts the whole issue, because that's what await does. In the synchronous if branch, the update and event firing are immediate, but the calling environment will still wait for the implicit Promise to resolve.
I think a bug should be logged on the MDN page because it certainly would be possible to come up with a less contorted example.

This super useful knowledge thank you. Apologies for a silly question, why will the calling environment still wait for the implicit Promise to resolve in the if case?

@MattStyles yes, I think that is true, but the reason I say the example is contrived is that it would be a big mistake to write code after a call to .getData() that assumes anything, given the implied "architecture" of the example.  If it's going to be based on handling a "load" event, then that's where the code should be, and it kind-of doesn't matter what the state of the world looks like right after the .getData() call, since that code shouldn't care.

The MDN example gets worse: implementing a load event on a (custom) element to cache URL dependent  data  opens up the possibility of calling getData multiple times with different URLs. When and if a load event is triggered, code has no way of telling to which URL it applies. Dispatching a load event at all in this code is wrong - it should not be there.

The example from MDN... maybe assumes the reader knows too much?
The problem that the example is trying to highlight is that the getData function is synchronous in one branch and asynchronous in the other, and this leads to bugs. Consider that the caller of getData doesn't understand they need an event listener and makes some assumptions about whether the .data property is populated:
element.getData();
element.data.forEach(console.log);

in the cached case, this code works fine. In the fetch case, it blows up with a runtime error. But there are even more pernicious problems:
element.getData();
await someAsyncFunctionThatReliesOnElementData();

Here we have potential for even more subtle bugs, because now in the fetch case the call to someAsyncFunctionThatReliesOnElementData might still succeed if it takes long enough that the data has come back (since it's async). In other words, we've now introduced a potential race condition on top of the other problems.
Now, all of this goes away if the caller just listens for the element's load event like they're supposed to, but the point is that by queueing the microtask in the cache case that you've eliminated an entire class of misuse of the API: anyone who assumes that it synchronously sets the .data property will get a fast failure instead of an intermittent one.
I think part of the problem is that this whole thing is horribly contrived. There are better ways to write something like this, included but probably not limited to removing the data property entirely and:

Having an async method for getting values (see Pointy's community wiki answer). No misuse possible.
Attaching the data to a CustomEvent and fire that. It's not as good as the async method because if listeners aren't registered and miss the event they don't get the data, but they can't misuse the element object.
Both of the above together.

In other words, the fix here is to refactor the element's API rather than muck around with queueMicrotask.

I just noticed that the example .getData() is set up as an => arrow function; it's Saturday so I may be extra slow but it seems dubious that this would be correct.

@Pointy oh wow you're right, who the hell wrote that?
